# Disk Partition Full

Tags: ubuntu, disk-usage

My `/` partition is full, to which I allotted about 30GB, and another partition of about 71GB is used for `/home` is quite empty.

I didn't install the dual boot myself and I quite don't know about why this works like this or something. I saw a tutorial as I was about to reinstall Linux on my PC but it made me more curious why things worked like this and were different from the tutorial. Like the video I watch booted the partition in a single disk partition but mine's with a 4GB swap space, 30GB for `/` directory, and 70GB for `/home`. As the 30GB partition is full I can't do or install much on my Linux system and there are lots of error and warning messages about my disk being full!

Can anyone help me fix this and throw some light on how the disk partitions work (in case of I need to reinstall).

What are the best practices while allotting the space to disk partitions?

Here is the output of: `sudo parted -l`

```
Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB  105MB   fat32           EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      106MB   123MB  16.8MB                  Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      123MB   249GB  249GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 4      249GB   404GB  155GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 6      404GB   434GB  30.7GB  ext4
 7      434GB   438GB  4096MB  linux-swap(v1)                                swap
 8      438GB   511GB  72.6GB  ext4
 5      511GB   512GB  1074MB  ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag
```

Output for `lsblk -e 7 -e`

```
NAME          FSTYPE    SIZE    FSUSED    MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1                 477G
├─nvme0n1p1   vfat      100M     56.1M    /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2              16M
├─nvme0n1p3   ntfs    231.7G
├─nvme0n1p4   ntfs    144.1G
├─nvme0n1p5   ntfs        1G
├─nvme0n1p6   ext4     28.6G     25.7G    /
├─nvme0n1p7   swap      3.8G              [SWAP]
└─nvme0n1p8   ext4     67.6G        5G    /home
```

Comment: A friend helped me install this and it was almost 2 years ago so I dont remember the details or why we did it even though I was present there with him.

Comment: Post these in question above, use your live installer: `sudo parted -l` & `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,UUID,mountpoint` Do you have good backups? That should be first before anything else.

Comment: I dont think I need a backup as I use my linux for college purposes that is moslty for my course work and do not keep any personal information on it.

Comment: I would recommend reinstall with deleting partitions 6, 7, and 8. On installation use /boot/efi (partition 1) for your EFI partition (do not format this one). Create a swap of 4GB on free space and use all remaining free space for / partition. In this way you will boot from /boot/efi, and use swap (4GB) and / (100GB) for your linux.

Comment: Please check your results following commands. First command is for checking free sizes of each mounted partition: `df -h -x tmpfs -x squashfs`. Second command is for checking most fat directory: `sudo du -h -d2 / --exclude=/sys --exclude=/proc --exclude=/dev --exclude=/srv`

Comment: PrathameshGujar, most of your work should be in your ordinary (non-root) user account. This is on `/home` so your own data should be using that partition. The root partition `/` is intended to be for the OS. Are you by any chance doing all your work while logged in (or using `sudo`) as the root user? If so, that's not standard practice and would explain why your `/` partition is full but `/home` is still empty

Comment: remove some /var/log and most /var/cache (e.g. /var/cache/apt/). Check also email (on local storage). If you didn't do something particular (databases, etc.) you should get much free disk.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi please don't post answers as comments.

Comment: Chris Davis, I mostly use linux for my college work and rest of my data is on windows disks. So linux is mostly used for download and running of softwares and the part that was holding the most space was libs section and no others media or my personal files I I used. This has happened previously too then I read online about manually uninstalling some things. So I uninstalled those things which I knew I installed such as texstudio, wireshark etc. Also I customised my GUI a bit so I guess it might take some memory too.

Answer (score 0):

#### How disk partitions works?

There are multiple benefits to have several partitions, with most important in my view: separate different partitions by access permission. Let `/` be modified only by root, which ensures that the user knows what he is doing then installing or uninstalling system-wide software. User should do his work only in `/home` partition.

#### Can you live without partitions at all?

Yes, you can. You can have just one single partition for the whole disk and have all `/`, `/home`, `/tmp`, `/var`, and even having swap as a file on the same partition. It is not recommended but possible.

Usually, people go this way if they have multiple physical HDDs and can put `/` on one physical drive, swap on another, `/home` on third and so on. Then each actual drive would have just one partition.

#### What is a best practice?

It is not possible to give definitve answer - each system administrator has his own. Usual practice - allow installer tool to decide the split. The reasoning here is that people who created the installer do know what they are doing (hopefully) and algorithm in the installer will do acceptable job. Consequently - if you have a very specific task for that computer, you can justifiably disagree with the partitioning suggested by installer, but such cases are extremely rare.

#### What to do if `/` run out of space?

1. ensure you are not using it for something other than storing system wide applications.
2. Look where `/tmp` and `*/var` directories are? If they are on the same partition as `/`, then try to use symlinks to move them to a different partition.
3. Backup your `/home`, to a different HDD or NAS. Reinstall OS with the partitioning suggested by installer, restore `/home` from backup. And never work as root again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried learning about disk partitions yesterday and got hold of some articles/videos which let me know enough. I reinstalled linux by myself this time and did allot space for swap and root partition (just two of them). I got some new options listed in my boot menu (or whatever menu appears when you are supposed to select which os you want to boot) The option was something like memtest86... I dont remember exactly. Can you tell me what is it for and also about where is my grub menu located this time? Does linux by default installs it with windows grub partition?

Comment: memtest is a tool to test memory. It is installed by some of Linux distributions and not a necessary part of new install. GRUB is a multi-boot tool. yes it is fairly standard nowadays, and most likely you have it, since you have boot menu, but its existence has nothing to do with Windows partition or partitioning in general. If creators of the distributive decided you need to have GRUB always - the installer will have it, even there is just one OS. But usually installer asks, do you need multi-boot or not.